# How can I properly fill a 2D Array table with an INI config file in LABVIEW?

Tags: file, config, ini, labview

Trying to fill a 2D Array table with config file through LABVIEW
The goal is to read an INI file through a table and be able to edit and save it to the INI file.
I'm struggling on filling the table properly.
EX. I have an INI file with X amount of KEYs and 5 Data Parameters.
Each row should show all 5 data parameters for each key.

my row currently looks like KEY1 DATA1, KEY2 DATA2 , KEY3 DATA3, etc....
my rows all repeat the same which i guess is a separate issue.
Any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

my row currently looks like KEY1 DATA1, KEY2 DATA2 , KEY3 DATA3, etc....
my rows all repeat the same which i guess is a separate issue.
Any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please can you show a sample of your INI file contents and the LabVIEW code you have so far, preferably saved as a [VI Snippet](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000x2PkCAI).